# Send live data from Main Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this bluetooth headset which sends messages everytime to the main Activity. Within the main activity, I have a handler which will process these messages and output accordingly.

I have a fragment which will make use of the messages. I cannot find a way to send live data from MainActivity to the fragment and I don't want to copy/paste the handler code to the fragment.

Is there a way to send live data from the mainActivity to the fragment. I am including some code for you to better understand.

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_dashboard);
        //Bluetooth headset which send live data
        tgDevice = new TGDevice(bluetoothAdapter, handler);
        tgDevice.connect(false);
    }


/**
 * Handles messages from TGDevice
 * @param menu
 * @return
 */
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case TGDevice.MSG_STATE_CHANGE:

                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case TGDevice.STATE_IDLE:
                        break;
                    case TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        //androidVersion.setText("Connecting...\n");
                        break;
                    case TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        //androidVersion.setText("Connected" + "\t" +wifiInfo.getSSID());
                        tgDevice.start();
                        break;
                    case TGDevice.STATE_NOT_FOUND:
                        //tv.append("Can't find\n");
                        break;
                    case TGDevice.STATE_NOT_PAIRED:
                        //tv.append("not paired\n");
                        break;
                    case TGDevice.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                        //tv.append("Disconnected\n");
                }

                break;
            case TGDevice.MSG_POOR_SIGNAL:
                poorSignalValue = msg.arg1;
                actionBar.setTitle("Signal: " + poorSignalValue);
                Log.v("Poor", "Signal: " + poorSignalValue + "\n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

The Fragment will make use of the poorsignal as well as other variables. What is the best way to do this? Other fragments will also make use of the TGDevice.

Comment: Is your fragment already added to the Activity when you want to send the data? Or you want the data to initialize the fragment?

Comment: @CarlosJimenez the fragment is already added to the Activity. It works fine. I just need to put data to it now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Your `Fragment` will register to an event, and your `Activity` will post updates.

Comment: This looks interesting. I think it will help to solve my problem. I'll have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Implement observer pattern where the fragment acts as an observer and the activity subject.For more info refer:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

You can also refer this link:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html.In this link the fragment acts subject and the activity as observer.You need to do the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

look in this link:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

you can call a function of the fragment from your main activity.

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity{
   MyFragment articleFrag = (MyFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);

 MyFragment.function();
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    ....

    public void function(){
       //do something ....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android View Model and Live data to share achieve the desired behaviour.

```
//View model
    public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
        private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

        public void select(Item item) {
            selected.setValue(item);
        }

        public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
            return selected;
        }
    }
    //Fragment
    public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
        private SharedViewModel model;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);

        }
    }
```

Make sure you pass  ViewModelProviders.of(**getActivity()**) instead of ViewModelProviders.of(**this**) when calling from fragment.

For more information: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)